# Use activity as a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I made an animation in activity class.Now i need to implement this activity in layout.So i open new activity class,and new xml.then call the layout in activity.But it doesnot work.

this is main1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<com.frame.animation.FrameAnimationActivity
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the activity class

```
public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main1);
 }
}
```

Note: I add the activity in Androidmanifest

Answer (score 0):

Each entry in your layout file should be a subclass of View.

You can't have an Activity in an XML file.

Move your code to a new class that inherits from View or ViewGroup.

Comment: A layout is made of View classes. An Activity displays a layout.

Comment: I know that.But what i want to know please wud u please do it in my code

Comment: Read up on LayoutInflater and View.